# JBoss 6.1 + PermGen space

Tags: java, jboss6.x, permgen, solaris-10

I have deployed Jboss 6.1 on Solaris and it was working fine. Then I did some FTP and Telnet and direct Root login was disabled. After that I'm getting PermGen space error.

What might be the reason for this error? Please help.

Error:

```
12:21:30,873 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PostClassLoader: name=vfs:///usr05/ccapp/app/jboss-6.1.0/server/srs/deploy/SRSEar.ear state=ClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PostClassLoader: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///usr05/ccapp/app/jboss-6.1.0/server/srs/deploy/SRSEar.ear
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

12:22:02,285 WARN  [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.jboss.ejb.Container: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

12:22:02,287 ERROR [BasicMBeanRegistry] Cannot register MBean: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/ejb/Container
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2436) [:1.6.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2556) [:1.6.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2566) [:1.6.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1412) [:1.6.0_45]
at org.jboss.mx.metadata.StandardMetaData.build(StandardMetaData.java:224) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.modelmbean.XMBean.<init>(XMBean.java:229) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.registry.BasicMBeanRegistry.registerMBean(BasicMBeanRegistry.java:205) [:6.0.0.GA]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_45]
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:138) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:140) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:90) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.installPlainMBean(ServiceCreator.java:233) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
at org.jboss.system.ServiceCreator.install(ServiceCreator.java:133) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.InstantiateAction.installAction(InstantiateAction.java:73) [:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.InstantiateAction.installAction(InstantiateAction.java:46) [:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:671) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.install(ServiceController.java:257) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:93) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:49) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unexpected error during load of: org.jboss.ejb.Container, msg=PermGen space
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:176) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:280) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1172) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) [:1.6.0_45]
... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are working around big Enterprise Application, you may face memory issues in Jboss. In order to solve this you need to increase JVM PermSize for Jboss. Lets see the steps to increase Jboss PermSize.

Note: I tested this settings under jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

### Windows

1. Edit`bin\standalone.conf.bat`
2. Change the MaxPermSize as per your requirement and save the file:

   `set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"`
3. Restart Jboss.

### Linux

1. Edit `bin/standalone.conf`
2. Change the MaxPermSize as per your requirement and save the file.

   `JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"`
3. Restart Jboss

Answer (score 0):

1. MyEclipse: Right click on JBoss x.x > Configure Server Connector > MyEclipse > Servers > JBoss > JBoss x.x > JDK
2. Paste `-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m` into the **Operational java VM arguments** field.